# Optimal server stack for Wordpress

Tags: nginx, varnish, optimization, mod-pagespeed, hhvm

There are numerous tutorials/articles(some even with benchmarks) on how to create an optimized stack to run Wordpress(or any dynamic site, for that matter). The site doesn't get frequently updated(best case scenario one article per week), so a long cache retention period would be fine. Oh, and i plan on running that on a dedicated server(or maybe a VPS, not sure yet, depends on cost and performance), so i will have full control of the system.

But i've failed to find one with the stack that seems(at least to me) to be ideal for such a scenario:
Linux(probably Debian),
Nginx - on steroids, with pagespeed and fastcgi,
MariaDB,
PHP - on steroids, with HHVM and maybe something to help with caching(no idea if there won'be conflicts), like PHP-FPM or PHP-APC,
Varnish.

So, in response to criticism, i have edited my main question to: 
What would be the optimal stack? Is pagespeed as good as it sounds? And what about HHVM? Does nginx's fastcgi work with PHP-FPM/PHP-APC?

Comment: PHP-FPM with Nginx proxy_pass and proxy_cache is well-known robust and fast configuration

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that, but wouldn't it be faster coupled with HHVM and mod_pagespeed(the essence of my question, what would be the best and fastest combination)?

Comment: it is, HHVM is probably the best option from performance point of view nowadays. Nevertheless it depends on read:write ratio. In case of semi-static web site environment (say, read:write could be 1000:1) it is difficult to measure the impact of backend. By the same reason stratus site generators are so popular for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Som if i manage to use cache to mostly statify my site(as i said, there aren't a lot of frequent updates), HHVM wouldn't make that much of a difference? Sooo a mod_pagespeed to optimise the HTML, nging and PHP-FPM to cache the optimised pages would be enough, no need to trouble myself with HHVM and Varnish?

Comment: Varnish doesn't make sense, you can use Nginx caching for the same purpose. In case of different ratio read:write it probably makes a big sense to invest a time in HHVM